# 502 Bad Gateway django nginx + gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am using post request to load a big amount of data from user input (textarea) to the database(`18k lines`)
And I get the `502 Bad Gateway` error

When I print `sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log`
I get this:

```
2018/09/06 10:21:04 [alert] 19688#19688: *3 open socket #22 left in connection 4
2018/09/06 10:21:04 [alert] 19688#19688: aborting
2018/09/06 11:04:32 [error] 20076#20076: *14 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.1$
```

This is only on my production server (nginx + gunicorn + postgres), on my dev server it works great.

**What do I do?**

I have also

Comment: What does your gunicorn log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing timeout in gunicorn helped to solve the issue